# Newbie trying to creating a Signal Event in MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Newbie here, just trying to create a signal event handler in response to an onclick menu item.
Aint working for me.
I click on the menu item, click signals, to the right of "Activated" where it says "Click to Add Handler", I type in "MyOnClick"
then it shoots me out an error. weird. 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I am running this in windows 7 under a vm on macbook pro. Windows is not sharing folders from Macbook Pro so shouldn't be a UNC issue. Pathways seem fine.

Any ideas?

Ben

Comment: Have you tried to double-click the signal, instead of typing in your own name for it?  If you double-click it will automatically make your stub code for you...

Comment: Hi Jeff, when I double click on Activated or one of the other signals handlers, the same error message comes up. Same error exists for creating a signal handler for button Clicked.

Comment: Strange, works for me...  Must be something wrong with the install???  Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on mac and windows with current monodevelop versions.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

It's annoying me so much! Must be some bug.

EDIT: I've solve it!

In source add method like this:

```
         protected virtual void onClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog (this, DialogFlags.Modal, 
MessageType.Error, ButtonsType.Close, "Some error"); 
        md.Response += delegate(object o, ResponseArgs args) { 
            if (args.ResponseId == ResponseType.Close) 
                Console.WriteLine ("Response: Closed");
            else 
                Console.WriteLine ("Other response happened."); 
        }; 
        md.Run (); 
        md.Destroy (); 
    }
```

Then switch to visual designer and instead double click on signal/method name just type in method name [this case] onClick (no brackets). This time a method is implemented and doesn't cause throwing error.

It work but is not as comfortable as double click.